# Android/Java: How to do multiple http requests in parallel and in repetition?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, retrofit

I've a list of news feeds that I'd like to read endlessly.

Current approach, **NewsReaderService**:

```
// ...
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    // run endlessly 
    while(true) { 

        // One thread per URL
        List<ReaderThread> threads = new ArrayList<>(); 

        // Prepare one ReaderThread per URL
        for (String url : readerUrls) {
            threads.add(new ReaderThread(url));
        }

        // Execute all threads
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads.size());
        executorService.invokeAll(tasks);

        // Wait for all threads to finish 

        // Start all over again
    }
}
// ...
```

**I don't like my current approach**, because:

1. `while(true)` doesn't feel right.
2. I'm creating new `ReaderThread`s and perform a `Retrofit` request *(which is another thread?)* within  each `ReaderThread`.
3. `ExecutorService` seems being used wrong.

I'd like to know the **proper solution** to reach my described goal. **Any idea?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not load each news feed one by one? I don't know what your current requirement is but I can't think of a scenario where you'd need to keep more than 2 or 3 active news feeds at the same time.

Comment: @Abbas If I do it one by one slow responses will slow down the queue. I've 1700 URLs to read and would like to use more cores (multi threading) to speed it up.

Comment: Even if you have a great number of URLs to go through, the user will probably not need responses from all 1700 URLs. If anything creating 1700 threads at the same time would only put an unreasonable strain on the system and resources.

Comment: If however you do require all responses from 1700 URLs then you should perhaps consider implementing lazy loading i.e. load a smaller chunk of perhaps 3. When you've done that load the next 3 URL responses. Alternatively you can create and manage a queue instead so you always have 3 active downloads. However I must say that it seems extraordinary that loading all the URLs right from the word go is unavoidable.